# log4r in Ruby on rails configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, logging, rubygems

I am trying to run ROR setup using Rails 4.1.8 over Unicorn server. But, facing one difficulty. I have integrated log4r with rails code for logging purpose. But, my logs are coming in production.log and only sql query related logs are going to my log file "log_new_2015-10-15.log".

Your quick help will be highly appreciable as i am stuck at very small but critical stage.
Below are basic configuration i have done.:
Step 1) Created at xyz_logger.rb in lib folder.
     xyz/lib/xyz_logger.rb:

```
require "log4r"
require "log4r/yamlconfigurator"
require 'log4r/outputter/datefileoutputter'

 module Logging        
    def logger
    return @logger if @logger

    Log4r::YamlConfigurator.load_yaml_file('config/log4r.yml')
    @logger=Log4r::Logger[Rails.env+'_logger']
    return @logger

    end

    end
```

Step 2) Included log4r gem in gemfile and run bundle install.

Step 3) In application.rb file, included the below three lines:
        Path: xyz/config/application.rb

```
 log4r_config= YAML.load_file(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),"log4r.yml"))
        YamlConfigurator.decode_yaml( log4r_config['log4r_config'] )
        config.logger = Log4r::Logger[Rails.env]
```

Step 4) log4r.yml in config folder:

```
log4r_config:

      loggers:
        - name      : production_logger
          level     : DEBUG
          trace     : 'false'
          outputters :
          - datefile
        - name      : development_logger
          level     : DEBUG
          trace     : 'true'
          outputters :
          - datefile
        - name      : sql_logger
          level     : DEBUG
          trace     : 'true'
          outputters :
          - datefile



      outputters:
      - type: DateFileOutputter
        name: datefile
        dirname: "log"
        filename: "log_new.log"
        formatter:
          date_pattern: '%H:%M:%S'
          pattern     : '%d %l : #{event.tracer[0].split(File::SEPARATOR)[-1]} :: %m '
          type        : PatternFormatter
```

Step 5) production.rb file: Added below lines.

```
config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
config.logger.level = Logger.const_get('INFO')
config.log_level    = :info
```

Step 6: Usage:
In one of my controller file [dummy date]:

```
require 'xyz_logger'
class TestController < ApplicationController
include Logging
  def populate_bean
     logger.info "Testing"
  end
end
```

Kindly note that I am using unicorn server and above configuration is working fine on thin & puma but not on unicorn server. Thanks in advance.